# sqlite query with multiple condition giving error : library routine called out of sequence

Tags: ios, sqlite

I am creating an app and using sqlite 3 for storing data.
Here is my code I am executing to fetch data

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement; 
NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT ID, HolderName, AccountNumber, BankName, Location FROM Accounts WHERE UserID='%@'",userID];

if(![name isEqualToString:@""]) 
{
    querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT ID, HolderName, AccountNumber, BankName, Location FROM Accounts WHERE UserID='%@' and HolderName='%@'",userID, name];
}
const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String]; 

if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

What is happening here, if name is empty then query(only with one condition in where clause) runs properly and fetches proper data but its giving error : library routine called out of sequence if name is not empty and query contains two conditions in where clause.
I am not sure what is wrong with it, I have searched a lot but found that query runs perfect with multiple conditions.
Please suggest me what should I do here.

Comment: why are you passing query multiple times....

Comment: query is single, I am updating that according to the name